# Startup time of apache.log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am struggling with `Log4j2` startup time, its taking around `36''` to start.

I have configured it using maven dependencies, and using version `2.4.1`. I have a test class that only request the logger and and post a log message. This is the output I am getting:

```
Wed Nov 25 10:14:09 CET 2015
DEBUG StatusLogger Using ShutdownCallbackRegistry class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Took 0.225008 seconds to load 155 plugins from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1b6d3586
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 38 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting LoggerContext[name=460141958, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@45c8e616]...
DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration started for context[name=460141958] at URI null (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@45c8e616) with optional ClassLoader: null
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'ConfigurationFactory' found 4 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Missing dependencies for Yaml support
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Missing dependencies for Json support
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@56cbfb61
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,208 main DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/pedromorales/DevelopmentDI/working/UnifiedUserPool/properties/log4j2.xml]
2015-11-25 10:14:45,211 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 77 plugins
2015-11-25 10:14:45,212 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2015-11-25 10:14:45,217 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=property, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,221 main DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,221 main DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=property, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property]. Searching for factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,222 main DEBUG Found factory method [createProperty]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property.createProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.String).
2015-11-25 10:14:45,243 main DEBUG TypeConverterRegistry initializing.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,244 main DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 21 plugins
2015-11-25 10:14:45,254 main DEBUG Calling createProperty on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property for element property with params(name="filename", value="uup")
2015-11-25 10:14:45,255 main DEBUG Built Plugin[name=property] OK from factory method.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,255 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=property, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,255 main DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,256 main DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=property, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property]. Searching for factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,256 main DEBUG Found factory method [createProperty]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property.createProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.String).
2015-11-25 10:14:45,257 main DEBUG Calling createProperty on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property for element property with params(name="loglevel", value="INFO")
2015-11-25 10:14:45,258 main DEBUG Built Plugin[name=property] OK from factory method.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,258 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=property, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,258 main DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,259 main DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=property, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property]. Searching for factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,259 main DEBUG Found factory method [createProperty]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property.createProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.String).
2015-11-25 10:14:45,260 main DEBUG Calling createProperty on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property for element property with params(name="rootlevel", value="ERROR")
2015-11-25 10:14:45,261 main DEBUG Built Plugin[name=property] OK from factory method.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,261 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=properties, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.PropertiesPlugin]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,262 main DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.PropertiesPlugin. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,262 main DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=properties, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.PropertiesPlugin]. Searching for factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,262 main DEBUG Found factory method [configureSubstitutor]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.StrLookup org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.PropertiesPlugin.configureSubstitutor(org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property[],org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration).
2015-11-25 10:14:45,269 main DEBUG Calling configureSubstitutor on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.PropertiesPlugin for element properties with params(={filename=uup, loglevel=INFO, rootlevel=ERROR}, Configuration(/Users/pedromorales/DevelopmentDI/working/UnifiedUserPool/properties/log4j2.xml))
2015-11-25 10:14:45,270 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 13 plugins
2015-11-25 10:14:45,271 main DEBUG Built Plugin[name=properties] OK from factory method.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,272 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,277 main DEBUG Found builder factory method [newBuilder]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$Builder org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.newBuilder().
2015-11-25 10:14:45,284 main DEBUG Calling build() on class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$Builder for element PatternLayout with params(pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n", null, Configuration(/Users/pedromorales/DevelopmentDI/working/UnifiedUserPool/properties/log4j2.xml), null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2015-11-25 10:14:45,285 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 38 plugins
2015-11-25 10:14:45,315 main DEBUG Built Plugin[name=layout] OK from builder factory method.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,315 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,318 main DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,319 main DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy]. Searching for factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,319 main DEBUG Found factory method [createPolicy]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(java.lang.String,java.lang.String).
2015-11-25 10:14:45,320 main DEBUG Calling createPolicy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy for element TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy with params(interval="null", modulate="null")
2015-11-25 10:14:45,321 main DEBUG Built Plugin[name=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy] OK from factory method.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,322 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,322 main DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,323 main DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy]. Searching for factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,323 main DEBUG Found factory method [createPolicy]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(java.lang.String).
2015-11-25 10:14:45,324 main DEBUG Calling createPolicy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy for element SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy with params(size="100 MB")
2015-11-25 10:14:45,326 main DEBUG Built Plugin[name=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy] OK from factory method.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,327 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=Policies, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,327 main DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,329 main DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=Policies, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy]. Searching for factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,330 main DEBUG Found factory method [createPolicy]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TriggeringPolicy[]).
2015-11-25 10:14:45,331 main DEBUG Calling createPolicy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy for element Policies with params(={TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=false), SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=104857600)})
2015-11-25 10:14:45,331 main DEBUG Built Plugin[name=Policies] OK from factory method.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,331 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,332 main DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,333 main DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender]. Searching for factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,333 main DEBUG Found factory method [createAppender]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TriggeringPolicy,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RolloverStrategy,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration).
2015-11-25 10:14:45,337 main DEBUG Calling createAppender on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile with params(fileName="../logs/uup.log", filePattern="../logs/archive/${date:yyyy-MM}/uup-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz", append="null", name="file", bufferedIO="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", Policies(CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=false), SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=104857600)])), null, PatternLayout(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n), null, ignoreExceptions="null", advertise="null", advertiseURI="null", Configuration(/Users/pedromorales/DevelopmentDI/working/UnifiedUserPool/properties/log4j2.xml))
2015-11-25 10:14:45,344 main DEBUG Starting RollingFileManager ../logs/uup.log
2015-11-25 10:14:45,346 main DEBUG PluginManager 'FileConverter' found 2 plugins
2015-11-25 10:14:45,351 main TRACE PatternProcessor.getNextTime returning 2015/11/25-00:00:00.000, nextFileTime=2015/11/24-00:00:00.000, prevFileTime=1970/01/01-01:00:00.000, current=2015/11/25-10:14:45.351, freq=DAILY
2015-11-25 10:14:45,352 main TRACE PatternProcessor.getNextTime returning 2015/11/25-00:00:00.000, nextFileTime=2015/11/24-00:00:00.000, prevFileTime=2015/11/24-00:00:00.000, current=2015/11/25-10:14:45.352, freq=DAILY
2015-11-25 10:14:45,353 main DEBUG Built Plugin[name=appender] OK from factory method.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,353 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,354 main DEBUG Found builder factory method [newBuilder]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$Builder org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.newBuilder().
2015-11-25 10:14:45,355 main DEBUG Calling build() on class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$Builder for element PatternLayout with params(pattern="%m%n", null, Configuration(/Users/pedromorales/DevelopmentDI/working/UnifiedUserPool/properties/log4j2.xml), null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2015-11-25 10:14:45,355 main DEBUG Built Plugin[name=layout] OK from builder factory method.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,356 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,358 main DEBUG Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,359 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 38 plugins
2015-11-25 10:14:45,360 main DEBUG Found builder factory method [newBuilder]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender$Builder org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender.newBuilder().
2015-11-25 10:14:45,366 main DEBUG No PluginVisitorStrategy found on annotation [interface org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.validation.constraints.Required]. Ignoring.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,367 main DEBUG Encountered type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout] which can only be checked for null.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,369 main DEBUG No PluginVisitorStrategy found on annotation [interface org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.validation.constraints.Required]. Ignoring.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,370 main DEBUG Encountered type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender$Target] which can only be checked for null.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,370 main DEBUG No PluginVisitorStrategy found on annotation [interface org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.validation.constraints.Required]. Ignoring.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,372 main DEBUG Calling build() on class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender$Builder for element Console with params(PatternLayout(%m%n), null, target="SYSTEM_OUT", name="STDOUT", follow="null", ignoreExceptions="null")
2015-11-25 10:14:45,372 main DEBUG Built Plugin[name=appender] OK from builder factory method.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,373 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,373 main DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,373 main DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin]. Searching for factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,374 main DEBUG Found factory method [createAppenders]: public static java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin.createAppenders(org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender[]).
2015-11-25 10:14:45,374 main DEBUG Calling createAppenders on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin for element appenders with params(={file, STDOUT})
2015-11-25 10:14:45,375 main DEBUG Built Plugin[name=appenders] OK from factory method.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,375 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,376 main DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,376 main DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef]. Searching for factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,376 main DEBUG Found factory method [createAppenderRef]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef.createAppenderRef(java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.Level,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter).
2015-11-25 10:14:45,377 main DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element AppenderRef with params(ref="STDOUT", level="null", null)
2015-11-25 10:14:45,378 main DEBUG Built Plugin[name=AppenderRef] OK from factory method.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,378 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,379 main DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,379 main DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig]. Searching for factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,380 main DEBUG Found factory method [createLogger]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.createLogger(java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.Level,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef[],org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property[],org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter).
2015-11-25 10:14:45,384 main DEBUG Calling createLogger on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig for element logger with params(additivity="false", level="INFO", name="com.havasmg.artemis", includeLocation="null", ={STDOUT}, ={}, Configuration(/Users/pedromorales/DevelopmentDI/working/UnifiedUserPool/properties/log4j2.xml), null)
2015-11-25 10:14:45,393 main DEBUG Built Plugin[name=logger] OK from factory method.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,394 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,394 main DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,395 main DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef]. Searching for factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,395 main DEBUG Found factory method [createAppenderRef]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef.createAppenderRef(java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.Level,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter).
2015-11-25 10:14:45,396 main DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element AppenderRef with params(ref="STDOUT", level="null", null)
2015-11-25 10:14:45,399 main DEBUG Built Plugin[name=AppenderRef] OK from factory method.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,400 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,400 main DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,401 main DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger]. Searching for factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,401 main DEBUG Found factory method [createLogger]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger.createLogger(java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.Level,java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef[],org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property[],org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter).
2015-11-25 10:14:45,409 main DEBUG Calling createLogger on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger for element root with params(additivity="null", level="ERROR", includeLocation="null", ={STDOUT}, ={}, Configuration(/Users/pedromorales/DevelopmentDI/working/UnifiedUserPool/properties/log4j2.xml), null)
2015-11-25 10:14:45,410 main DEBUG Built Plugin[name=root] OK from factory method.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,411 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,412 main DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,413 main DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin]. Searching for factory method...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,415 main DEBUG Found factory method [createLoggers]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Loggers org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin.createLoggers(org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig[]).
2015-11-25 10:14:45,416 main DEBUG Calling createLoggers on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin for element loggers with params(={com.havasmg.artemis, root})
2015-11-25 10:14:45,416 main DEBUG Built Plugin[name=loggers] OK from factory method.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,418 main DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/pedromorales/DevelopmentDI/working/UnifiedUserPool/properties/log4j2.xml] initialized
2015-11-25 10:14:45,418 main DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/pedromorales/DevelopmentDI/working/UnifiedUserPool/properties/log4j2.xml]
2015-11-25 10:14:45,419 main DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/pedromorales/DevelopmentDI/working/UnifiedUserPool/properties/log4j2.xml] OK.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,419 main TRACE Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@28feb3fa...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,420 main TRACE AbstractConfiguration notified 0 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,424 main TRACE AbstractConfiguration stopped 0 AsyncLoggerConfigs.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,424 main TRACE AbstractConfiguration stopped 0 AsyncAppenders.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,425 main TRACE AbstractConfiguration notified 0 ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,426 main TRACE AbstractConfiguration stopped 1 Appenders.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,427 main TRACE AbstractConfiguration stopped 0 LoggerConfigs.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,427 main DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@28feb3fa OK
2015-11-25 10:14:45,572 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=460141958
2015-11-25 10:14:45,576 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=460141958,component=StatusLogger
2015-11-25 10:14:45,578 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=460141958,component=ContextSelector
2015-11-25 10:14:45,584 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=460141958,component=Loggers,name=
2015-11-25 10:14:45,587 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=460141958,component=Loggers,name=com.havasmg.artemis
2015-11-25 10:14:45,591 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=460141958,component=Appenders,name=file
2015-11-25 10:14:45,592 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=460141958,component=Appenders,name=STDOUT
2015-11-25 10:14:45,600 main DEBUG Using default SystemClock for timestamps
2015-11-25 10:14:45,605 main DEBUG Could not set AsyncLogger NanoClock. Ignoring: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lmax/disruptor/EventFactory
2015-11-25 10:14:45,606 main DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=460141958] at URI null (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@45c8e616) with optional ClassLoader: null
2015-11-25 10:14:45,606 main DEBUG Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,607 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=460141958, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@45c8e616] started OK.
Wed Nov 25 10:14:45 CET 2015
tester
Wed Nov 25 10:14:45 CET 2015

2015-11-25 10:14:45,940 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopping LoggerContext[name=460141958, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@45c8e616]
2015-11-25 10:14:45,942 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopping LoggerContext[name=460141958, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@45c8e616]...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,942 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Unregistering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=460141958
2015-11-25 10:14:45,943 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Unregistering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=460141958,component=StatusLogger
2015-11-25 10:14:45,943 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Unregistering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=460141958,component=ContextSelector
2015-11-25 10:14:45,944 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Unregistering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=460141958,component=Loggers,name=com.havasmg.artemis
2015-11-25 10:14:45,944 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Unregistering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=460141958,component=Loggers,name=
2015-11-25 10:14:45,945 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Unregistering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=460141958,component=Appenders,name=STDOUT
2015-11-25 10:14:45,945 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Unregistering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=460141958,component=Appenders,name=file
2015-11-25 10:14:45,946 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE Stopping XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/pedromorales/DevelopmentDI/working/UnifiedUserPool/properties/log4j2.xml]...
2015-11-25 10:14:45,946 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE AbstractConfiguration notified 2 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,946 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE AbstractConfiguration stopped 0 AsyncLoggerConfigs.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,947 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE AbstractConfiguration stopped 0 AsyncAppenders.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,947 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE AbstractConfiguration notified 2 ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,947 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Shutting down RollingFileManager ../logs/uup.log
2015-11-25 10:14:45,948 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE AbstractConfiguration stopped 2 Appenders.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,948 pool-1-thread-1 TRACE AbstractConfiguration stopped 2 LoggerConfigs.
2015-11-25 10:14:45,948 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopped XmlConfiguration[location=/Users/pedromorales/DevelopmentDI/working/UnifiedUserPool/properties/log4j2.xml] OK
2015-11-25 10:14:45,948 pool-1-thread-1 DEBUG Stopped LoggerContext[name=460141958, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@45c8e616]...
```

As you can see in the logs, it starts and in the `getLogger()` method stop to log during the 36 seconds, and then show the log configuration.

Could you help me? I guess it is not normal, but we do not know how to continue.

Comment: Please format the stack trace.

Comment: Do you have any custom log4j2 plugins? Are the log4j2 jars modified in any way? (Did you combine them into a single jar file, for example?)

Comment: Hi Remko, No I have not modify anything, just add the 2 jars using a maven dependency, and no custom plugins.

Comment: Would you mind raising this on the [Log4j issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2) so that the whole team can take a look at it? Please include the status log output again, your configuration, and any other info on your environment you think may be relevant.

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?